# Bash script didn't stop running even a compile error happens

Tags: java, bash, maven

The refine script on Linux does not do a good job at stopping if it needs to compile OpenRefine and compilation errors occur.

To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior (from a git clone of the repository):

First, clean with ./refine clean
Then, introduce some compilation error somewhere, such as by doing rm ./extensions/wikibase/src/org/openrefine/wikibase/qa/QAWarning.java
Finally, run ./refine
Current Results

The compilation fails in the Wikibase extension but the refine script still attempts to start OpenRefine:

```
...
[ERROR] extensions/wikibase/src/org/openrefine/wikibase/qa/scrutinizers/NewEntityScrutinizer.java:[104,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class QAWarning
[ERROR]   location: class org.openrefine.wikibase.qa.scrutinizers.NewEntityScrutinizer
[ERROR] extensions/wikibase/src/org/openrefine/wikibase/qa/scrutinizers/NewEntityScrutinizer.java:[104,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class QAWarning
[ERROR]   location: class org.openrefine.wikibase.qa.scrutinizers.NewEntityScrutinizer
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :wikibase


15:54:05.840 [            refine_server] Starting Server bound to '127.0.0.1:3333' (0ms)
15:54:05.975 [            refine_server] refine.memory size: 1400M JVM Max heap: 1468006400 bytes (135ms)
15:54:06.359 [            refine_server] Initializing context: '/' from '/home/user/OpenRefine/main/webapp' (384ms)
15:54:06.948 [            refine_server] Starting autoreloading scanner...  (589ms)
15:54:13.478 [                   refine] Starting OpenRefine 3.8-SNAPSHOT [acca2dd]... (6530ms)
15:54:13.495 [                   refine] initializing FileProjectManager with dir (17ms)
...
```

Expected Behavior

The refine script should stop at the end of the failing Maven build.

https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/5698

I found out the control of running server is these lines:

```
 RUN_CMD=("$JAVA" -cp "$CLASSPATH" "${OPTS[@]}" "com.google.refine.Refine")

    echo ""
    
    

    if [ -z "$FORK" ] ; then
        exec "${RUN_CMD[@]}"
    else
        "${RUN_CMD[@]}" &
        REFINE_PID="$!"
    fi
```

But I don't how to catch the wikibase error and then stop this run_cmd.

Comment: By default, shell scripts don't exit on errors. You can make them do that with `set -e`, but its idea of what's an exit-worthy error often doesn't match up with a reasonable person's (see [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"), so it's not very reliable. Personally, I just add error checking to important steps in the script, which can be as simple as `importantCommand || exit`.

Comment: @otter : In the posted script, the only command in question is `$RUN_CMD[@]`. Are you refering to **this** command to fail?

Comment: When you execute a script, its the script itself that is responsible for proper error handling and process cleanup. Once you write a fully self contained script, you wont have any more problems with build

Comment: @user1934428 I am expecting if any of the components' build processes fail, it will not execute $RUN_CMD[@]

Comment: My impression is that you're asking us to debug a third party's build/install script. But that is not the spirit of StackOverflow. Please read about [mcve] and look at their code. Can you boil the problem down to something readers can test without having goto an external site and run that build process? For debugging help, maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info , skipping the version information at the top, and searching for "Before asking about problematic code" and "How to turn bad code into a good question". (Or file a bug report with the project?) Good Luck

Comment: You don't show in your script, how you build your comments, so I can't say how you can determine their failure.

Comment: @shellter  Thanks for your reply and guidance, I am new here and will read through the information you provided.

Comment: AND you are relying on OpenRefine AFTER you are attempting to build some other X project. (as user193... has pointed out). Please edit your question to put a name to "project X" and include a github URL for it. (Not how we like to do things, but I have a little time today, maybe I can look at this). Good luck.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't intended as a place to get a bash tutorial. The two things needed are to 1) figure out how to get the Java compilation error to propagate to the Maven exit (if it isn't already) and 2) how to check the Maven exit code and modify the execution flow. As an intern applying to the OpenRefine project, you shouldn't be relying on StackOverflow to do this for you.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I solved this problem by using importantCommand || exit. The only thing I found out is to know when and where the compile fail and add on "|| exit". Thanks so much for saving my day!

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your kindness. I appreciate your words and your trying to help.

Comment: @otter : Glad you found a solution to your problem. `|| exit` is certainly effective. Dig into why `ImportantCommand` is failing and you'll be on your way. I was thinking of a comment about how much you can learn from just a simple example like `set -vx ; true ; false ; true && true ; false && true ; false || true ; true || true ; true || false ; set +vx`. Best to take each section between `;` chars and copy/paste to a command line and inspect what is happening for each segment. You could append `; echo $?` to each segment .  ...

Comment: (Commands return 0 for true/success and non-zero numbers when there are prroblems. ). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Thank you! I saved your suggestion and will definitely try these out. All the best :).